# This user ID has voted too many times (Android App)

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When voting on different sites for questions that I'm following, I finally got an error when upvoting, saying that `Quota for the vote of question exceeded, 24 hour quota for this user is 30`. I may have voted a total of 30 times since I got the app (months ago), and across different sites, but I guarantee that after a weekend of no StackExchange, I did not vote 30 times when I initially turned it on.
This works ok on voting for answers

Version 0.1.59, version 0.1.60

Comment: I've actually seen the same message, when I know I have not exceeded my votes allotted. This also happens on comment votes.

Comment: I would have up voted your comment, but I'm at the max there as well

Comment: Well, I'm on my notebook now, so I can up vote yours ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Done@

Comment: Also confirmed for me that voting works fine on answers. Just not questions or comments.

Comment: Yup I added that as soon as I noticed

Comment: On the website, so I can up vote your comment ;)

Comment: I just noticed that I can vote properly on SO itself, just not here. Going to try a couple other sites... update: yup, just seems to be here for me.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I can't vote on ANY question, on any site, from the app. Even my Freelancing site where I'm a mod

Comment: Hmmm... Argh for that!

Comment: But 15 upvotes, I'm sure a dev has seen it by now. I'll wait patiently, and keep posting updated versions if it doesn't fix itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have upped the API throttles for voting on questions and answers.  Let us know if you continue to see issues here.

Comment: Not letting me yet. I haven't updated my SE app since this morning though

Comment: This won't require an app update since it's server side.  The existing throttles are active for 24 hours so about this time tomorrow it should be good to go.

Comment: Alright, I'll try tomorrow and report back. Thanks

Comment: It's working properly now

Comment: I get the same error when voting on comments from the android app. My error message is `Quota for the vote of question exceeded, 24 hour quota for this user is 100`, but I haven't voted on any comments from the android app lately (due to this bug).

Comment: @user000001 I'm gonna say you'll need to open a new question, as that sounds like a different issue; I have been able to vote, up to the 24 from previously