# Cannot favorite a question in android app

Tags: bug, android-app, bookmarks

I tried to favorite [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10497/804), it kept giving me an error saying the question is already favorited.

Comment: Only one user can favorite a question? It is not showing up in your profile but that might be cached...

Comment: @rene - of course not. This appears to be a bug in the android app, not the site.

Comment: @rene If I open it in a browser it shows it has 0 favorites, so no I don't think that's the case.

Comment: I just favourited that question from my normal desktop browser so the verdict is the android-app.

Comment: I was able to replicate this in 0.1.64; I tried to favorite [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204190/175498) meta question, but couldn't.

Comment: No repro on Android 5.0 and app version 1.0.82.

Comment: @AlE. This was probably fixed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222962/cannot-favorite-once-up-voted?lq=1 Though we need a mod or SE staff to mark it as complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug seems to be fixed now.

There a [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223052/172297) marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) which probably fixed the problem.