# How to favorite a question from Android app?

Tags: support, questions, android-app, bookmarks

I've found an interesting question when browsing Freelancers.SE. I've tried to star (favorite) the question but I couldn't find the option...

How to star a question from the Android app?

Comment: Well, there is [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204603/152859) so it means such option exists, don't you have actions menu for each question, e.g. on top?

Comment: No, there are only Settings and Help in the menu.

Comment: Weird, hard to believe they removed such feature... wish I had the app myself, guess we'll just have to wait for someone who can answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tap the timestamp on the right bottom side of the question (next to the user card).  You will get a menu in which you will see an option for "Favorite".