# How to follow activity on favorite questions from Android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, bookmarks

I know there is a way to [favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213149/251274) from the app, but I cannot find a practical way to  follow the activity on the questions I favorited. 
The only way I found was to type `infavorites:mine` into the search box and sort by `active`. But there is no way to bookmark a search, and repeatedly typing this search command on a small screen is no fun.

I understand not all desktop site features can be built into the app. But following the activity on my favorite questions is precisely the sort of things I'm likely to do from a mobile device.