# Favourites Page on iOS App

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, bookmarks

I would like to have a page listing all the questions I marked as favourite, same as the [desktop version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites).

Also, I think the desktop version, the star, is much more intuitive and easier to find. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223862/how-to-follow-activity-on-favorite-questions-from-android-app

Comment: The request for star instead of the current way to favorite is actually a separate request, please consider posting it as new feature request.

Answer (score 3):

The Favorite Questions UI is coming.  I'm attempting to make favorite questions double as a reading list in the iOS app:

- The list is offline cached for bad connectivity.
- The list updates instantly when you favorite/unfavorite a question.
- Any question you favorite gets cached for periods of bad connectivity.
- When you first view the list, the 10 most recently added questions are cached.

I'd prefer to handle the star UI as a separate request.

[image]

Comment: I know this page is a work in progress, especially for editing the visible tabs. Can I give two minor suggestions though? First, change the icons. They're the same as other tabs. My Profile should be of a single user, not multiple. Favorite Questions should be a star. Second, `Favorite Questions` is way too cramped to fit on the tab bar. Maybe just `Favorites`?

Comment: The icons are being designed. Not a bad idea to shorten the name in the tab bar.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? This sounds like a great feature update!

Comment: @Gary this is in the 1.2.0 App Store release. Favoriting is in a menu when you tap "Answered" or "Edited" below a question. (This will be better in the next release.) Favorite questions are in the last tab of the site view.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for that! I'm wondering if it's also possible to create a page that shows my favorites across ALL sites? Just like on Stack Exchange's desktop site now.