# Cross-site favourites list for mobile apps

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

The mobile apps, both for Android and iOS, would be far better suited to actually help answer questions if they had a list of questions that the user „starred“. There are some questions around here asking for such a listing, but it seemed it fell by the wayside some time around 2014 (see, e.g., [Favourites Page on iOS App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233752/favourites-page-on-ios-app)).

Currently, the only way to even get at one‘s favourites is the very unintuitive and rather hidden saved-search approach described in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243538, but that is restricted to individual sites.

I would suggest offering the user a central place for all their starred questions *across all sites*, which would be a bit different than these older proposals.

I would see the following advantages:

- the current „mark as favourite“ action in the app would not feel so write-only (question to the app‘s maintainers: do you have numbers on how many users use the saved-search trick to get their favourites?)
- the list could be used to gather helpful advice for users who frequent several sites professionally (an admin might, e.g., want to collect articles from Serverfault, Unix/Linux, Superuser and Webapps in one place)
- the list could be used to gather articles for researching a „proper answer“ when a mobile user is back at his or her workstation („I found this interesting problem on the train, but I‘ll need my Linux lab machine to work out a solution“)

What do you all think?

Comment: The SE mobile app is more or less officially deprecated. It will see no further development, not even bug fixes, for the foreseeable future. The team has decided to focus their resources on the new responsive design for the site as the primary mobile interface. There is a supported SO-only app, but obviously this desire request isn’t applicable to it.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the info! I assume you‘re in contact with the responsible people? If so, I‘d suggest that this should be mentioned on the respective App Store pages. Thanks! And just to add a statistics point: I am very much in favour of native UI approaches over „responsive web site for everybody“, so I‘m sad to see the app getting no new features any more. But from a business perspective, I guess it‘ll make sense...