# Favourite option in mobile application

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Please include an 'Add Favourite' option for questions in the Stack Exchange mobile application, which is already available on the stack exchange sites on the web.

Comment: There already is in the iOS app, just below the question. Is this specific to the android app?

Comment: Yes. It's specific to the Android app.

Comment: Sorry. It's my ignorance. I found it just below the question. I was searching it in another location as what we see in the web. Should I delete thus question now ?

Comment: Whoops! I'm an iOS user, so wouldn't know! Probably a good idea to delete the question, yes. =)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I will be deleting this in a while.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213149/how-to-favorite-a-question-from-android-app

Comment: Couldn't find an option to delete in android app. Really sorry for this.

Comment: There is no delete option there; but there is the option to open in a browser, from where you can delete.