# Feature Request: Bookmark / Follow a question

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I want to follow a question (with a bookmark of some sort), but there doesn't appear to be any way to do so in the Android app.

There is a favourite button, but once you add a question as a favourite there doesn't appear to be any way to view your favourite questions within the app. If there is a way, and I'm not finding it, then it needs to be made more visible. For example, a "Favourite Questions" item in the main menu.

Comment: Two totally different feature requests here. First of all, please separate them into separate questions.

Comment: [Bookmarking is already supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213149/how-to-favorite-a-question-from-android-app), so please remove this part and keep the part about too short error duration.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even realise this would get posted as a question. I simply clicked on the Feedback link within the app, and selected 'Feature request'. It was unclear that this was going to get posted as a question for users to scrutinise - so that itself is also some more feedback on using the app. However, I will edit my above question with more details.

Comment: Yeah, it's not trivial, but that's just how it works. As for list of favorites you're correct, it's not available easily, but there is a workaround as described in the answer to the dupe question.