# Cannot favorite once up voted

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, up-votes, bookmarks

I'm not sure whether this is exactly the same bug as [Cannot favorite a question in android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204603/241749) or whether this is a new bug.

If you up vote a question and then attempt to add it to favorites too you get `Question is already favorited`:

[image: Screenshot]

This also happens if you up vote on the web site and then try to favorite it from Android. If you don't up vote or if you favorite it first and then up vote it appears to work fine.

Comment: It isn't throttled? So if you wait five seconds between the upvote and the favoriting?

Comment: If that's the case then maybe the bug is that the error message should reflect that.

Comment: @rene No, that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like our check for "has this question been favorited by this user" was just checking if the user had made any type of vote at all on the question, not just a favorite vote. This is being fixed server-side so you won't need to update the application to see it.